# Why does this nuclear explosion keep glowing for so long?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Looking at the videos of nuclear tests recently declassified by LLNL, California, I found this video.

https://youtu.be/TiKBI_Zg0J8

I wonder why the nuclear explosion keeps glowing for so long, when it is done in mid air(apparantely) unlike this video

https://youtu.be/XnrLY-phipw

which is ground based explosion, and which glows only for a few seconds.

Can someone explain the reason?

Comment: I can't answer because I'm not sure of all of the following, but some of those films are taken at 2400 frames per second, whereas the Hardtack Nutmeg is clearly close to 25 frames a second (witness the seagulls flying off when the shock wave arrives to get an idea of time). The first video is of the fireball, which lasts only a short time, so I am guessing that the first video was filmed at 2400 frames a second. Also, the two explosions were very different size: that Dominic Harlem explosion was 1.2 megatons whereas the Hardtack Nutmeg was 25kT. There is a definite lengthening of flash with...

Comment: .... higher yield, but I can't find a reference at the moment.